# Conditional Data Templates in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate

How would it be possible to choose a different datatemplate accroding the a field in the data binding source?
I would have 2 different DataTemplates

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateLabel">
    <Label Width="60" Height="25" Background="Red">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </Label>
</DataTemplate>



<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateTxtBox">
    <TextBox Width="60" Height="25" Background="Red" Text="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

if (isText) Then use  DataTemplateTxtBox ELSE use DataTemplateLabel) Is this possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a `DataTemplateSelector` and assign it to the `ContentTemplateSelector` property (or `ItemTemplateSelector` if it is in an `ItemsControl`)

Answer (score 0):

This is more an indirect answer, but by doing polymorphism (i.e. abandoning IsText property and answering the question using a different type) you can define a DataTemplate for each different type.